# How Can I make 2D array with different object of class?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have three classes.The first class is Node that has 2 variables and the second class is Instance with two variables.The third class which is called Decision has two 2-D arraies the fist one is an 2D array with different types of classes. How Can I make 2D array with different objects of classes(Nodes and Instances)? The second 2D array(y) is type Integer which each dimension is a variable of class Node and class Intances. How can I say for example y[0][0]=1

public class Nodes {

```
private int nodeID;
private String nodeType;

  public Nodes(int nodeID, String nodeType) {

    this.nodeID = nodeID;
    this.nodeType = nodeType;
}
public int getNodeID() {
    return nodeID;
}
public void setNodeID(int nodeID) {
    this.nodeID = nodeID;
}
public String getNodeType() {
    return nodeType;
}
public void setNodeType(String nodeType) {
    this.nodeType = nodeType;
}
```

}

public class Instances {

```
private int type;
private int traffic;

public Instances(int Type, int traffic) {

    this.type = type;
    this.traffic = traffic;
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public int getTraffic() {
    return traffic;
}
public void setTraffic(int traffic) {
    this.traffic = traffic;
}
```

}

public class Decision {

```
Nodes node1=new Nodes();
Instances ins1= new Instances();


      private Nodes Instances x[][];    
      private int [][] y=new int [node1.getNodeID()][ins1.gettype()];
//private Nodes[] node;
//private Instances[] ins;
```

}

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: I think if you make both classes extend the same class then you can have an array of that class

Answer (score 0):

simply you can't , the multi dimensional arrays are most to be considered as an array of array .

> How Can I make 2D array with different objects of classes(Nodes and Instances)?

I think it will be easy to do something very similar with java `List` and `Map` ,it does have all the classes you need to go with .

Comment: Do you have any example of using List and Map